# generating network traffic with iperf without a server

Tags: networking, network-traffic, iperf

I need to exercise some hardware by sending a network traffic with it. While it is doing it I will probing some of the lines with an oscilloscope. Need to verify signaling. The problem is that I won't be able to connect to any server during the test. Many reasons for that, one of each is that hardware isn't complete yet.

Does anyone know if there is a away to generate network traffic with `iperf` without using a server? All I need is to just send some data, don't need to know if it was received. If there isn't can someone point me to a tool that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

iperf UDP will do it, you just need to make sure there is an ARP entry for the destination (enter it manually) or use a multicast destination which doesn't require ARP, e.g. iperf -u -c 239.1.1.1 -b 10M

Comment: I'm not a networking engineer. Can you explain the meaning of 239.1.1.1? I know it is an IP but why this one specifically?

Comment: It's an ip multicast destination address.  It's one source to many destinations.  (Unicast is a one to one mapping.)